# How to get the values from JsonObject using jquery and ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I have an JsonObject which is returned from the spring controller to populate select boxes. But I am not able to load it in Ajax

Here is my Jquery Code

```
$("#category").click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "loadSelectBox",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            $("#category").empty();
            var options = '';
            for(var i = 0; i <= data.length - 1; i++){
                options += "<option value='" + data[i].id + "'>" + data[i].name + "</option>";
            }
            $("#category").append(options);
            $("#category").trigger('chosen:updated'); 
        }
    });

})
```

My controller Code is

```
@PostMapping(name="loadSelectBox")
    public JSONObject getCategoryJsonObj() throws Exception{
        System.out.println("loadSelectBox:::::: ");
        JSONObject catJsonObj=new JSONObject();
        try {
            ArrayList<CategoryDTO> catDTOList=globalCatList;
            System.out.println("catDTOList::: "  +catDTOList);
            ArrayList<String> dbList=rawDataProcessService.getCurrentCategoriesInserted(structureID);
            System.out.println("dbList:: "  +dbList);

            System.out.println("catDTOList before removing : "  +catDTOList.size());
            if(dbList!=null && dbList.size() >0){
                for(int db=0;db<dbList.size();db++){
                    String dbData=dbList.get(db);
                    for(int cat=0;cat<catDTOList.size();cat++){
                        CategoryDTO dto=catDTOList.get(cat);
                        String currentData=dto.getCategory();
                        if(dbData.trim().equals(currentData)){
                            catDTOList.remove(cat);
                        }

                    }
                }
                System.out.println("catDTOList after removing : "  +catDTOList.size());
                for(int cat=0;cat<catDTOList.size();cat++){
                    CategoryDTO categoryDTO=catDTOList.get(cat);
                    String categoryValue=categoryDTO.getCategory();
                    System.out.println("categoryValue: ::" + categoryValue);
                    catJsonObj.put(categoryValue, categoryValue);
                }
                System.out.println("catJsonObjLLL " +catJsonObj);
            }else{

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return catJsonObj;

    }
```

JSONObject from the spring controller will be as following Key value pair:

```
 {"MONTH":"MONTH","TYPE OF DATA 5":"TYPE OF DATA 5","TYPE OF DATA 3":"TYPE OF DATA 3","TYPE OF DATA 4":"TYPE OF DATA 4"}
```

I am not able to load the above jsonObject values into the select box.

Help is appreciated, Thanks

Comment: can you show response json data of ajax

Comment: I am not getting response data, seems like its not success

Comment: add error handler in ajax to get the error messages

Comment: success: function(data){...},error:function(xhr,error_string,error_msg){ console.log(error_msg);console.log(error_string); }

Comment: I am getting 404 error in ajax

Comment: your url is right *url: "loadSelectBox",*  ?

Comment: yes URL is correct and i get JsonObject values in controller

Comment: return catJsonObj; will not return json string to ajax . you need to send browser output like out.println(catJsonObj);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150249/discussion-between-shankara-nethran-s-n-and-jyothi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That kind of forloop is used to iterate through array of data.In your case its just an object.So iterate through the object to retrieve key value pair.

Change you for loop like this

```
for(var key in data){
      options += "<option value='" + key + "'>" + data[key] + "</option>";
}
```

Thus the js will look like

```
$("#category").click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "loadSelectBox",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            $("#category").empty();
            var options = '';
            for(var key in data){
                options += "<option value='" + key + "'>" + data[key] + "</option>";
            }
            $("#category").append(options);
            $("#category").trigger('chosen:updated'); 
        },
        error: function(response){
            alert("ERROR\n"+response);
            console.log(response);
        },
    });
}) ;
```

**Note**: Don not send json with keys with space separator.

In yous sample response "TYPE OF DATA 5" these are not valid json keys.Either separate with underscore("TYPE_OF_DATA_5") or use 'camelCase' notation for referring keys

Comment: I have done as you said above, but still i am getting 404 error and select box is not loaded

Comment: check your response. 404 is page not found error.Which is thrown by the server.add an error block to show the response.

Comment: I have changed the keys to "TYPE_OF_DATA_3":"TYPE OF DATA 3" eventhough i am not getting the expected result

Comment: JS updated with error block.Use this to find out the error. Check the url field in the ajax (url: "loadSelectBox",). Is that correct???

Comment: Yes now I am getting Error [object Object] in alert

Comment: Print on console.instead of alert use console.log(response).And check the console window for expanded error. Its definitely server response error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150250/discussion-between-aneesh-rs-and-shankara-nethran-s-n).

Answer (score 1):

**1st :** `return catJsonObj;` will not return `json string` to `ajax` . you need to return  browser output like `System.out.println(catJsonObj);`

```
return catJsonObj;
```

change to

```
System.out.println(catJsonObj);
```

**Note :** Also remove unwanted `System.out.println(..);`

**2nd:** Follow @Aneesh RS steps  to poppulate the drop down

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, Since it was Server side isse,
I have just added @ResponseBody in My controller class.

```
@PostMapping(name="loadSelectBox")
    @ResponseBody
    public JSONObject getCategoryJsonObj() throws Exception{
// Logics
}
```